# Refactor a loop to call an async process

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a process that goes through a loop.  During each iteration of the loop, it calls out to an external web service and then adds a object to an EntityFramework repository. The call to the external service is wrapped in a static method. Typically the loop only has one or two iterations but up to 4 is currently possible with the UI.  (Each iteration represents an insurance quote).

It seems that this would benefit from being refactored as an asynchronous process.  How do I set this up so that each iteration occurs in a seperate thread, and the commit waits until all threads are completed?

```
public class ProcessRequest
{
    private IUnitOfWork = unitOfWork;

    public ProcessRequest(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        unitOfWork = uow;
    }

    public void Execute(MyRequestParams p)
    {
        foreach (Quote q in p.Quotes)
        {
            q.Premium = QuoteService.GetQuote(q);
            unitOfWork.GetRepository<Quote>().Add(q);
        }

        unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}

public static class QuoteService
{
    public static decimal GetQuote(Quote quote)
    {
        //I've simplified proprietary code to single line that calls an external service
        return ExternalWebService.GetQuote(quote.Deductible);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this WPF, WinForms, Webforms, MVC, Web API?  (Very very relevant to the answer)

Comment: This is within a business layer of an n-tiered solution.  The business layer is called by an MVC front end.  There have been discussions of converting the business layer to a Restful API that UI then calls.  The UI is low traffic currently (intra-net with handful of users) but might get scaled up in not to distant future.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two different things: one is how to execute the loop *in parallel*, where each iteration occurs (potentially) on a separate thread; this is completely different to executing the entire loop as an *asynchronous process* which means the thread that initiates it won't wait for it to complete. I assume you meant the first, i.e. that you want to parallelize the iterations in the loop but still block until all of them are done.

Without knowing anything about the context in which this runs, one straightforward way would be to use Parallel Extensions, specifically Parallel Foreach:

```
public void Execute(MyRequestParams p)
{
  Parallel.ForEach(p.Quotes, q => {
    q.Premium = QuoteService.GetQuote(q);
    unitOfWork.GetRepository<Quote>().Add(q);
  });

  unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Or maybe something like:

```
public void Execute(MyRequestParams p)
{
  Parallel.ForEach(p.Quotes, q => {
    q.Premium = QuoteService.GetQuote(q);
  });

  unitOfWork.GetRepository<Quote>().AddAll(p.Quotes);
  unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

This depends heavily on the thread-safety what you're dealing with.

Comment: You're right, I didn't ask the question clearly. I was trying to say that each iteration should be asynchronous, that it shouldn't wait for one iteration to stop before starting the next. You worded it better then I did.  Thanks for your response, I like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If most of your work is I/O, im not sure i'd go for spinning up a new thread, as you are wasting most of your time idle waiting for your service/DB to reply.

i'd try to go with a async approach:

```
public async Task Execute(MyRequestParams p)
{
  foreach (var quote in p.Quotes)
  {
     //Of course, you'll need an async endpoint.
     var q.Premium = await QuoteService.GetQuoteAsync(q);
  }

  unitOfWork.GetRepository<Quote>().AddAll(p.Quotes);
  await unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

With this approach, you save the overhead of spinning up new threads and letting them be idle most of the time.
Hope this makes sense, of course you'd have to have access to an async endpoint of the webservice, and use Entity Framework v6.

Comment: I like this solution as well. I'm going to have to read up on the difference between Parellel.ForEach and Task/Await. I'll confirm that I have an asynch endopint for the webservice. Thanks again.

Comment: Basically: using async/await runs the loop serially (one iteration after the other), but each _await_ed part can optionally be invoked on a separate thread which frees your original thread from having to worry about it (this is relevant if the original thread is a webserver worker thread in which case you don't want to keep it waiting). The Parallel.ForEach solution still holds the original worker thread while waiting for the other threads to concurrently do the work (instead of serially). They're really solving different problems (and can be combined if you need to).

Comment: Async/Await enables you to write I/O based asynchronous work in a synchronous fashion way. Lets say you want to send a HTTP message over the wire. You generate the HTTP message and send it off to the web service, and the thread from that point on sits there, waiting for the web service to retrieve the response. Async enabled you to tell that request "Listen, im going to return to my caller right now, but let me know when you're finished and ill jump back to the point where we left off". This enables you to not waist any thread resources on work that is basically blocking I/O operations.